# Why echoing an expression with unset variables prints 0?

Tags: php

I found this strange behaviour:

```
$a = $b + $c;
echo $a; //prints 0
```

prints 0  while this:

```
$a = $b;
echo $a; //doesn't print anything
```

doesn't print anything.
Is it explainable in a meaningful way?

Comment: What are the values?

Comment: No values, I don't set anything.

Comment: There is a function behind the `+` operator that will return an integer (0) whereas the assignation operator `=` doesn't always return an integer.

Comment: @Ferex You should change your error/warning setting so it shows: `PHP Notice:  Undefined variable`. By default, any variable goes to `null`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In one context (`$a = $b + $c`), they are being converted into numbers because of the `+` operator and the same would apply with all  mathematical operators: `+, *, -, /`.

In the other, it's just an empty variable (undefined variables are set to NULL) being coerced into a string by the `echo`.

See http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php

```
echo "Cast to int becomes: " . (integer) NULL; // 0

echo "Cast to string becomes" . (string) NULL; // (Empty string)
```

Comment: Be more explicit about operators behavior so your question will be meaningful for all. Thanks.

Comment: @Answers_Seeker The values are converted if they are around a  `+` operator? What extra information are you looking for? Feel free to improve the answer.

Comment: The fact that it's a function behind the `+` operator and extend this to other types and operators (i.e. if someone asks the same question but not with `+` or integers for instance). It's just for content improvement purpose don't take it as an offense.

Comment: @Answers_Seeker It doesn't offend me at all, I'd like to improve the answer but I don't follow what extra explanation you are suggesting.

Answer (score 3):

This is a side effect of type juggling. Undefined variables `$b` and `$c` are equivalent to `null`. In PHP, `$a = null + null` is equivalent to `$a = (int) null + (int) null` which is the same as `$a = 0 + 0`. This is the reason that `$a` equals 0.

It follows that `$a = $b` is the same as `$a = null`, so when you `echo $a`, nothing is printed.

This is a decent reference that explains type juggling - http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php

Answer (score 0):

Type casting. PHP tries to guess to most fitting variable type on context and casts the values accordingly.

```
<?php

$a = null;
$b = null;
var_dump($a . $b); // string(0) ""
var_dump($a + $b); // 0
var_dump($a / $b); // float(NAN), also warns about Division by zero
var_dump($a - $b); // 0
var_dump($a * $b); // 0
```

It's also why you can do:

```
echo "8 beers" + 5; // 13
```